# How to comment my XML files in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, comments, xml-comments

I am learning Android and want to be able to add line comments to my XML so I can remind myself what things are doing.

Is there an accepted practice for this, or is it possible in Android Studio? I recall reading that comments in XML are hard, so I wanted to know if that was also considered true here.

Comment: You can comment a line using the same what you use on `HTML files`. `"<!--Line comment-->"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above you can comment in XML just like this:

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

But in android studio you can very easily toggle comment just by selecting what you want to comment and then pressing:

```
CTRL + /
```

This not only for XML but also for your java code for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible. I'm not sure if there is an accepted practice, but you can accomplish leaving a comment like this

```
<!-- comment goes here -->
```

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1 seems to not like this: http://imgur.com/nVlww5a and as far as I can remember it never has.

Comment: @Timestretch - this actually does work, as long as you are not putting these comments within the definition of a single view.  You can comment out whole views.

Comment: @KristyWelsh Can you elaborate?

Comment: @KristyWelsh Commenting out entire views works, but it is pretty crippling to only be able to do this.  Is this a limitation of XML or Android Studio's interpretation of it?

Comment: @Timestretch - I think this is a limitation of XML.

Answer (score 1):

Same as in all XML applications: 
Just use `<!-- ... -->` to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in XML aren't too tough. You have to do it like this:

For example

`<!--  This is a comment -->`

Please don't hesitate to ask for anymore help. The above should work in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac then command is command(button which looks like Windows start button ) + / 
If you are on Windows then it is 
Cntrl + /

Try and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio DOLPHIN version I have tried using the 
and the file does NOT like it. It produces errors when used.
I don't know about XML files much, but this AndroidManifest.xml file does not like this. Any other tips that might work? This file is error free before the comment line is added.

[image: picture of errors]